# How to get the first element id in each function jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a data grid and each row has checkbox with same class name. I need to get the checkbox id. I got the error the object doesn't support.

webpage:

```
<table>
  <tr><td>
    <span class="chkClass">
        <input name="$ctl02$chk" id="dgrd_ctl02_chk" type="checkbox">
    </span>
  <td/><tr/>
  <tr><td>
    <span class="chkClass">
        <input name="$ctl03$chk" id="dgrd_ctl03_chk" type="checkbox">
    </span>
  <td/><tr/>
</table>
```

There is my code:

```
function Selectbox() {
    $('.chkClass).each(function () {
 var chkbox = this.firstChild;
    alert(chkbox.attr('id'));
          });
```

}

Comment: you didn't add ' here -> `$('.chkClass)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's firstElementChild not firstChild and you should call 'attr' function on $(chkbox) not on chkbox. https://jsfiddle.net/L5r0q4go/

```
     $('.chkClass').each(function () {
        var chkbox = this.firstElementChild;
        console.log($(chkbox).attr('id'));
     });

     //dgrd_ctl02_chk  
     //dgrd_ctl03_chk
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use like this.

```
$('.chkClass').each(function () {
       alert($(this).find('input:checkbox').attr('id')); 
 });
```

Output:

```
//dgrd_ctl02_chk  
 //dgrd_ctl03_chk
```

https://jsfiddle.net/euLatc9o/4/